# Does Flutter work without Google Play Services?

Tags: flutter, google-play-services

I mean to build a flutter app in an Android device that does not support Google Play Services nor am I interested in having them installed.
Does flutter need those services to work?
(I know that the use of Google Sign-In, Firebase and the like should be impossible without them and I'm ok with that.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flutter works just fine without Google Play services as it does not depend on them.

However to use anything Google(Firestore, Cloud Function, Firebase, Google sign-in, etc), you'll need the Google Play Services.

Comment: Most of features in firebase does not required google play service now.